# jQuery: Disable all links within a div - replace with inner content

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all links within a div and replace it with the content that was there.

i.e.

```
<div><a href="/blah.html">My super link</a></div>
```

to

```
<div>My super link</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [`.replacewith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and a function, like this:

```
​$("div a").replaceWith(​​​​function() { return $(this).text();​ });​
```

[You can see a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qd3E2/)

Comment: @Chris - Use `.contents()` instead of `.text()` in that case, see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/qd3E2/2/

Answer (score 4):

Hmm - mine is similar to the other quicker-typists' answers, but I would have thought `html()` would have been what you wanted to use:

```
$('div a').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: +1 - While ours work for the example, this would work in all applicable cases.

Comment: I have some `&nbsp;`'s inside my `<a>` and this seems to throw an exception : "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I accomplished this by doing the following:

1 - selecting all anchors that I wanted to disable
2 - removing all events associated with the anchor
3 - replace the href attribute value with a #
4 - add a click event to the anchor which does nothing

The below code sample below is cut from my plugin.  The plugin also has code to 
enable the anchor back again. It may give you ideas.

You can also download my plugin at ( http://www.dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget ) and use it or cut out what you need from it.

```
$('a').each(function(e) {
  // disable events on anchor
  this._disableEvents($(this));

  // save off the HREF value
  var href = inp.attr("href");
  if (href != undefined) {
    // save the HREF attribute value and remove the value
    inp.data(dataAnchorHref, href);
    inp.attr("href", "#");
  }
  // override the click event for the anchor
  inp.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // decorate the anchor with a disabled look
  inp.addClass('ui-state-disabled');

});

_disableEvents : function(inp) {
  var de = $.Event("disableEvents");
  this._trigger("disableEvents", de, inp);
  if (de.isDefaultPrevented()) { return; }

  var widgetEventPrefix = this.widgetEventPrefix;
  // jQuery adds an "events" data attribute on the element when events are registered
  var events = inp.data("events");
  if (events != undefined) {    
    var savedEvents = [];
    // loop through each event found on the element...
    $.each(events, function(eventName, handlers) {
      $.each(handlers, function(index) {
      var handler = handlers[index];
      if (handler != undefined) {
        // save the event and handler
        var eventObj = {
          'eventName' : eventName, 
          'handler' : handler
        };
        if (eventName.indexOf(widgetEventPrefix) < 0) {
          // unbinding a non widget event
          savedEvents.push(eventObj);
          inp.unbind(eventName);
        }
      }             });
    });
    // store the saved events as a data attribute on the element
    inp.data(dataSavedEvents, savedEvents);
  }         
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the outline of a solution along with the link for the complete package :-)